# How can I make user stay connected once SignedIn and make user Signout on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, authentication, logout

I have a problem with my sign in code I did on reactJs. When I login using email and password, it connects successfully and redirect me to the app.js component. 
But once signed in, if I go back to the login page it still goes to the login page and asks for the login credentials meanwhile the user just logged in.

How can I handle that in react, so that the login page will be displayed to the user only if he clicks on the sign out button after he was logged in?

and also I am confused on how to apply changes on my user component so that when the user is logged in, it will display the only the sign out button to him and how can I handle this sign out?
Any suggestions? I have been doing research on this but all my attempts failed.

Thank you in advance!

User Component

```
class User extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (

            <div>
                <div className="float-left">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Log in</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Sign in</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to save the logged in state in a top level component. This is can be done easily if you're using the context  API or redux. To not let the user access the login page after the user has logged in, you have to do a comparison in ComponentDidMount, ComponentWillMount or getDerivedStateFromProps. (Preferably better to do it in getDerivedStateFromProps) to see if the user is logged in. If the user is logged in redirect the user to the homepage upon entering the login page. Its similar to how you protect routes from being accessed by unauthorized users.

Comment: ok thank you, but what comparison do I have to do? with which value? can I have a preview for this ?

Comment: What i mean by comparison is that you have to check if the user is logged in by comparing it with a global state where you save if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: I did a comparison in my code that does that if (user && user.authenticated === true) { }. this checks if the user is authenticated

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, but I usually use cookie to save my token that I got from the login service so I can keep navigating throughout the page.

The token would expire after some time, so every time I visit the site, I check to the server whether my token is expired or not, if it's not expired, I can access the site immediately, if it's expired, I will need to log in again.

Your got that problem because you save the user's state as react state, react state won't persist on page refresh, and even on different sibling component, so you would need to keep logging in to access the site.

Well at least save the authentication state to either cookies/sessionstorage, there are libraries for react and many examples on the internet to do this. You're better off reading those since they're already explained in great detail that won't fit in this answer.

======== edit

For a Cookie based authentication, you can use package [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) package. Save a Cookie after you successfully log in, like (really rough example):

```
Cookies.set('is_authenticated', 'true');
```

then you can get the values by:

```
Cookies.get('is_authenticated');
```

Then you can do a simple check whether the value of `is_authenticated` is a string of `true` or not. If it's, you can still access the page.

You can call this method on the main page, like on `componentDidMount` so it will be checked everytime.

And If you log out the page, just delete the value, like:

```
Cookies.remove('is_authenticated');
```

So when you call

```
Cookies.get('is_authenticated');
```

the value will be `undefined` so you need to login to access the app.

Please do note that this is a rough example. If you're logging in from a server, that server should provide you with some sort of token, and you save that token instead on the browser cookies.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I try to research on this earlier but I didn't understand much. And most examples were using react redux and I already started coding without that. Can I have maybe a preview?